# Splitting conjoining words in R

Tags: r, regex, string, pattern-matching, character

I am trying to split string that is structured like:

```
string <- c("ThisThat","OneTwo","LeftRight","RightHere")
```

and turn it into:

```
>string
[1] "This That"  "One Two"    "Left Right" "Right Here"
```

I have tried numerous functions in the 'stringr' and 'stringi' package. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

does this work for you?

```
gsub("([A-Z])", " \\1", string) %>% trimws()
[1] "This That"  "One Two"    "Left Right" "Right Here"
```

Comment: Or `sub("([a-z])([A-Z])", "\\1 \\2", string)` and not have to use `trimws`

Comment: or slightly more robustly `sub("([:lower:])([:upper:])","\\1 \\2",string)`

Comment: @BenBolker shouldn't it be `sub("([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])","\\1 \\2",string)` ? With only one `[` I get "ThisThat"   "OneTwo"     "LeftRight"  "RightHe re"